# What does ";" mean in the link

Tags: web-application, web-browser, url

In some links, I found  `;`.

Example: `https://example.com/index.php?action=pm;sa=send;u=1`

What does that mean? Is it a web application firewall?

Comment: it's a simple separation of parameters.

Comment: Is this on topic for InfoSec?

Comment: It's called a Matrix URL. Is legit. http://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/MatrixURIs.html

Comment: @DavidGrinberg no. It's definitely not.

Comment: SecResearcher - I see all your questions have been closed so far. Please read [about] and [ask] to understand what questions are okay here.

Answer (score 5):

The [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/appendix/notes.html#h-B.2.2) spec allows you to use `;` as a separator instead of `&`. This is just a standard link with a different delimiter.

> We recommend that HTTP server implementors, and in particular, CGI implementors support the use of ";" in place of "&" to save authors the trouble of escaping "&" characters in this manner.

As mentioned by Mike Ounsworth, there is nothing security related to this.

Answer (score 3):

It is a delimiter, it allows the server to separate the argument `action=pm;sa=send;u=1` into three separate statements:

```
action=pm
sa=send
u=1
```

There is absolutely nothing security-related about it.